# Loop through variables with composite name

Tags: css, less

What am I doing wrong here?

**What I'm doing:**

body {

```
&.green {
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
        color: @color-green;
    }
}
```

}

**What I'm trying to do:**

```
@color-green: #1ED261;
```

body {

```
@colors: green, red, blue;

.for-each(@color-name in @colors) {

    &.@{color-name} {
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
            color: @color-@color-name; << IS THIS THE PROBLEM?
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can make a variable that makes and stores the string like `color-green` from loop variable. Below is a sample code for the same.

```
@color-green: #1ED261;
@color-red: #D22A1E;
@color-blue: #1E84D2;

body {
  @colors: green, red, blue;

  each(@colors, {
    &.@{value} {
      h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
        @color: %('color-%s', @value); //This creates and stores the variable name we will need in next step
        color1: @@color; //use that variable 
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Swaroop! It seems I need a plugin to make this work, right? I tried the Lists plugin but somehow I can't make it work :/ 
https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists#less-plugin-lists

Comment: @UXTE You don't need any plugin, above code is in pure less . These are the document links.
http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each
http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions--format
http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-variables

Comment: @UXTE if the above answer solves the problem, please mark it selected.